# "Name The Template Parameter" Odd Definition

Tags: c++

```
template <bool, class t, class u>// why is bool here,class booltype=bool. Are they equivalent?
struct if_
{
    typedef typename t type;
};

template<class t, class u>
struct if_<false,  t,  u>   // what does the <false,t,u> mean？   
{
    typedef typename u type;
};
```

The code if from an article named "name the template parameter ". I can't understand the  definition of the both struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### EDIT: Moved the most important part first:

```
if_<true, int, double>::type;  // this is int
if_<false, int, double>::type; // this is double
```

This conveniently defines a type that can conditionally be defined at compile-time.

#### Old Answer:

```
template <bool, class t, class u>// why is bool here,class booltype=bool. Are they equivalent?
struct if_
{
    typedef typename t type;
};
```

This means the first parameter passed to the template is a `bool`.

It's not equivalent to `class booltype=bool`. That would be a default `typename` for the template.

```
template<class t, class u>
struct if_<false,  t,  u>   // what does the <false,t,u> mean？   
{
    typedef typename u type;
};
```

This is a specialization of your `struct`. If the first parameter passed to the template is false, this it what the `struct` is defined as.

Basically, assume:

```
if_<true, int, double> x;
//is defined as
//struct if_
//{
//    typedef int type;
//};
```

and

```
if_<false, int, double> x;
//is defined as
//struct if_
//{
//    typedef double type;
//};
```

The notation basically tells what to typedef - if the first parameter is `true`, `typedef` the second parameter, otherwise the third.

Comment: `template<class t, class u> `      why it's not template <bool, class t, class u>                                              `struct if_<false,  t,  u>`

Comment: @unkonwn_kid that's just the syntax when you provide a partial specialization.

Comment: @unkonwn_kid no problem. For partial specializations, you need only provide the parameters that are not yet specialized. In your case you can omit the first one, as you already provided it - false.

Answer (score 0):

The first is a general template definition of type `if_`.  The bool is a template parameter (template parameters can be types or integral values)

The second is a partial specialization of the same template.  PArtial specialization means that you set some of the template parameters, but not all.

Which one gets used is decided like this: if there is an excplicit specialization for the actual template parameters, that specialization is used, otherwise the non-specialized (the forst definition in this case).  The non-specialized version acts a "default" selection

Answer (score 0):

`struct if_<false,  t,  u>` is a partial sspecialization of the primary template `if_` which is instantiated by the compiler whenever the first parameter of the template has the value `false`, regardless of the other two "type-parameters". You're dealing with "non-type" template parameters here. The primary purpose of this construction is to select either the type `t` or type `u`, depending on the value of the first parameter, so that

```
if_<true, int, double>::type
```

will be of type `int`

and

```
if_<false, int, double>::type
```

will be of type `double`. Admittedly quite difficult to grasp if it's your "first contact" with c++ meta-programming, but basically you get an equivalent of the traditional `if` statement evaluated by the compiler at compile-time.